# tfs webpageControl in Clustered server environment

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are trying to use a WebpageControl from a TFS 2015 update 3 Work item. The control references a small web site that allows the user to create a set of Task associated with a PBI or Bug.

When you click on the tab the web page goes and gets the work item data currently displayed, retrieves any Tasks that currently exist and presents a list of Tasks with different names which can be created. The list items are check boxes. If a Task with a name as one of the selection items already exists the checkbox is grayed out.

Once the user has checked the Tasks they want created they click on a button which calls back to the web site, creates the Tasks, Reloads the task list, and redisplays.

It all works great. Sometimes. There appears to be a problem with the fact the TFS Servers are in a cluster with a common URL routed through an F5. Users address TFS with http://tfs.mycompany.com:1234/tfs/.... but this is routed to SERVER1.mycompany.com OR SERVER2.mycompany.com.

The Code for the WebpageControl in TFS is

```
<Tab Label="Task Gen">
            <Control Type="WebpageControl" LabelPosition="Left">
              <WebpageControlOptions AllowScript="true" ReloadOnParamChange="true">
                <Link UrlRoot="http://SERVER02.mycompany.com:8001" UrlPath="?WIT={0}&amp;CollectionName=XXX">
                  <Param Index="0" Value="System.Id" />
                </Link>
              </WebpageControlOptions>
            </Control>
          </Tab>
```

Sometimes the user will get a message :

**Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.**

then

```
[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 10.11.12.13
    Port: 56587
    Referer: http://SERVER2.mycompany.com:8001/?WIT=123456&CollectionName=xxxx
    Path: /default.aspx
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; AcanoClient; Zoom 3.6.0)
    ViewState: v+KaQTHxuY9zf11uYfES7....
```

I have added the machine key to my small web site but the error sometimes continues. I have specified a specific server to be used in the Web Page control.

Does the Machine Key need to be on the TFS Server?
It is really trying to contact a different server and if so why?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info `Validation of viewstate MAC failed`. 
There are multiple causes such as

- Cause 1: The web application is running in a farm (multi-server
  environment)
- Cause 2: The worker process uses the IIS 7.0 application pool
  identity
- .... more

The issue most due to *cause1*, you could give a try with  Resolution 1a: Create an explicit  element and Resolution 1b: Enable affinity in the load balancer. More details about the resolution please refer this topic from MSDN: [**Resolving view state message authentication code (MAC) errors**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors)

Comment: I did add a machine key to the web site referenced by the WebpageControl. I'm not sure that's doing any good or even needed since that site is referenced with a url that addresses a specific server. Not an site addressed through a farm.

Comment: The problem is I do not know where to put the Machine Key. It would seem it should be on the site referenced by the TFS WebpageControl but it I am always referencing servers explicitly from this control I don't understand why that would be necessary.